# How to add custom NSView to Window

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview

I know how to do this in iOS but cannot figure it how to it in Cocoa.

I want to capture keyboard events and I think I need to override the acceptsFirstResponder method to accomplish that (keyDown method being triggered). So I created a class extending NSCustomView and tried to add it in the main Window but I just cannot understand how to do it. So far I added a Custom View to the main View then tried to add it programmatically like:

```
TestView *view = [[TestView alloc] init];
[[_window contentView] addSubview:view];
```

but this is not working. So how can I do this?

Comment: Tutorials or whatever are welcomed, I'm %&#$ lost! :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To see if the view has been added to a window, you can override the view's `viewDidMoveToWindow` method and log the value of `[self window]` to check (if it's `nil` then the view has been removed from a window):

```
- (void)viewDidMoveToWindow
{
    NSLog(@"window=%p", [self window]);
    [super viewDidMoveToWindow];
}
```

You should be subclassing `NSView`, not `NSCustomView`, and `initWithFrame` is the designated initializer for `NSView`, not `init`.

Try:

```
TestView *view = [[TestView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 100, 200)];
[[_window contentView] addSubview:view];
```

Comment: @momo No problem.  The `NSMakeRect` stuff will need some work, depending on whether you want the window to fit the view or vice-versa.